# select boxes counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this fiddle and i would like to make it count the number of boxes that are selected.
Now it shows the numbers of the boxes.

Any idea how to do it??

```
   $(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
 filter: "td.cs",

      stop: function(){
        var result = $("#select-result").empty();
        var result2 = $("#result2");
      $('.ui-selecting:gt(31)').removeClass("ui-selecting");

          if($(".ui-selected").length>90)
          {
     $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(i,e){
         if(i>3)
         {
         $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
         }
     });   
return;              
          }

     $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(){

          var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
          result.append(cabbage);
        });

        var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text(); 
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult); 
      }
    });
  });
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/44/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just try this withih `stop()`:

```
$(".ui-selected").length
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/46/)**

#### NOTE

To get all selected div you need to place above code like following:

```
 alert($(".ui-selected").length); // here to place

 if ($(".ui-selected").length > 4) {
      $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(i, e) {
       if (i > 3) {
             $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
       }
      });
      return;  // because you've used a return here
 }

 alert($(".ui-selected").length); // so not to place here
```

Comment: i have checked the demo you send me. is what i wanted but when i select more than 4 it dons't show me the result

Comment: thanks by the way the limit is 4 though. my problem was to show the result of maximum selected boxes allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
...
stop: function(){
    console.log('you selected %d cells', $('.ui-selected').length);
...
```

Comment: can you add it my fiddle to see  i am still a begginer